# Using regexp to search for the string matching multiple words arranged in random

Tags: regex

How can I write the regexp to match multiple words in random order?

For example, let's assume the following lines:

```
Dave Imma Car Pom Dive
Dive Dome Dare
Imma Car Ryan
Pyro Dave Imma Dive
Lunar Happy Dave
```

I want to search the string for the one matching "Dave" "Imma" and "Dive", expecting the 1st and 4th line.  Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't a good job for regular expressions to do. Regular expressions are for pattern matching but your task contains logic that is hard to express in a pattern. Also, you haven't specified what language.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on doing this with regex, you can use lookahead:

```
s.matches("(?=.*Dave)(?=.*Imma)(?=.*Dive).*")
```

Regex is not the most efficient way of doing this, though.

Answer (score 2):

in *nix, you can use awk

if its in order

```
awk '/Dave.*Imma.*Dive/' file
```

if its not in order

```
awk '/Dave/ && /Imma/ && /Dive/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if  ((matches "/(Dave|Imma|Dive) (Dave|Imma|Dive) (Dave|Imma|Dive)/")
 && (contains("Dave")) && (contains("Imma")) && (contains("Dive")))
{
    // this will work in 90% of cases.
}
```

I don't think it's possible to do this exactly, though. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] lines = fullData.split("\n");
String[] names = {"Dave", "Imma", "Dive"};
ArrayList matches = new ArrayList();

for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++){
    for(String name : names){
        // If any of the names in the list isn't found
        // then this line isn't a match
        if(!lines[i].contains(name)){
            continue;
        }
    }
    // If we made it this far, all of the names were found
    matches.add(i);
}
// matches now contains {1, 4}
```

If you don't need to know where the matches are, it can be simplified to:

```
String[] lines = fullData.split("\n");
String[] names = {"Dave", "Imma", "Dive"};

for(String line : lines){
    for(String name : names){
        // If any of the names in the list isn't found
        // then this line isn't a match
        if(!line.contains(name)){
            continue;
        }
    }
    // If we made it this far, all of the names were found

    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should the following lines match?

```
Dave Imma Dave
Dave Imma Dive Imma
```

I'm guessing the first one shouldn't because it doesn't contain all three names, but are duplicates okay?  If not, this regex does the trick:

```
^(?:\b(?:(?!(?:Dave|Imma|Dive)\b)\w+[ \t]+)*(?:Dave()|Imma()|Dive())[ \t]*){3}$\1\2\3
```

I use the word "trick" advisedly. :) This proves that a regex can do the job, but I wouldn't expect to see this regex in any serious application.  You'd be much better off writing a method for this purpose.

(By the way, if duplicates *are* allowed, just remove the `$`.)

EDIT: Another question: should the names be matched only in the form of complete words?  In other words, should these lines match?

```
DaveCar PomDive Imma
DaveImmaDive
```

So far, the only other answer that enforces both uniqueness and complete words is Coronatus's, and it fails to match lines with extra words, like these:

```
Dave Imma Car Pom Dive
Pyro Dave Imma Dive
```